# Codensity monad preserves some colimit?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

Let $j: A \to B$ be a functor.

When $j$ has a left adjoint $L$, the codensity monad $\text{Ran}_jj$ will coincide with the monad $jL$. Since a left adjoint preserves all colimits, it is easy to observe the following:

> Rem 1. Let $j$ be a functor with a left adjoint. Then if $j$ preserves a family of colimits, so does $\text{Ran}_jj$.

I hope that this is still true removing the assumption of having a left adjoint. Since my $j$ has values in a presheaf category, I wrote the end-formula, but I see no good reason for which the monad should preserve those colimits preserved by $j$.

> Q1. Is the statement of Rem 1 still true removing the assumption of having a left adjoint? You can still assume that $j$ preserve all limits, if needed.
>
> Q2. If it is false, are the some natural assumption that will make it true? (For example, $j$ fully faithful.)

Comment: My gut instinct is that this is false. If you're looking for examples, I recommend this paper by Tom Leinster: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.3606.pdf also summarized and discussed here: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/09/where_do_monads_come_from.html